# Best way to handle large DB result set and maintain UI responsiveness

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq, architecture

I am writing a WPF and Entity Framework application to catalogue all the photos on a PC. As I find an image I save it to a temporary list and then every few seconds write the list of new items to a database so I am not constantly connecting to the DB. If the app crashes I can detect that and resume using the records in the database.

I show all the items in a listbox. To populate it I do a database LINQ query using '.ToList' every few seconds, so I can update the display and also filter or sort the items. But clearly as the list gets larger the query takes longer and the interface hangs briefly while the interface updates.

To improve responsiveness I have thought about trying out a ObservableCollection, so that the listbox items are updated live, and I dont have to make expensive DB queries. But I have read that with Entity Framework I am not supposed to keep a long running context, instead I am to just create and destroy it as required. Using an observable collection of entities seems to imply that the ObservableCollection is an in-memory collection of all the results. And if there are 1,000,000 image files then I dont want to have a massive collection in memory, so my preference is to get results from the database as needed. But then how do I update the UI responsively with live results?

Comment: I find it hard to picture (ugh) what exactly you're doing here. But can FileSystemWatcher help you out?

Comment: @GertArnold I think filesystemwatcher is good for picking up images if it is active when they are saved to disk. But in this application I am starting from scratch and finding all pictures on the disk, then showing them all in a Lisbox. A bit like Picasa I guess.